# Is it possible to have multiple domain policy for different servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, domain-controller, group-policy

In my organization, there is 1 domain with 13 production servers joined to it. Recently, we realized that the default domain policy that is applied to the production servers have minimal security policy defined. In short, the production servers are not hardened.

Would it be possible for me to create another domain policy with security policy defined and apply it to 2 new servers which will be joined to the same domain?

How do I specifically apply this new domain policy to these 2 servers only without affecting the existing production servers?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! There appears to be **little to no research done on this issue up front**.  It is recommended that you post things you've already tried, options you are considering, or errors that you are experiencing.  The more details you provide (logs, screenshots, etc.), the better the experts here can assist you.

Comment: To point you in the right direction, I would check out [Group Policy Basics](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb310732.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

1. Create your policy intended for servers.
2. Create an OU for the servers you want to apply the policy to.
3. Move the servers you want the policy to apply to into the OU.
4. Apply the policy to the OU.

If you later decide you want to apply the policy to your other production servers, you can move them into the OU you created above.